# Internet Explorer converting single apostrophies to &#39;

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-7, apostrophe

I have added the below script to an webpage which opens a pop-up and pulls content from a google drive (I've converted it to XXXX for demo below).

```
<a href="Supplier Compliance elearning" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://googledrive.com/host/XXXXX/XXXXXX.htm','Supplier Compliance eLearning','width=960,height=672,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no');return false"><strong>Click here</strong></a>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and Mozilla, yet Internet Explorer 7 is converting single apostrophies to

```
&#39;
```

as you can see in the script below.

```
<a href="Supplier Compliance elearning" onclick="javascript:window.open(&#39;https://googledrive.com/host/0B0NRXxkC_4WpejhRb0x5cmxKakk/PLMS_Rego.htm&#39;,&#39;Supplier Compliance eLearning&#39;,&#39;width=960,height=672,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no&#39;);return false"><strong>Click here</strong></a></div>
```

Any thoughts on how I can get it to work correctly in all three browsers?

Comment: `&#39;` is just another way of expressing `'` in HTML. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.The link isn't working in IE, but it does in Chrome and Mozilla, when I looked at the source, this is the difference I could see. Is there anything else in my script that would prevent IE from interpretting it the same as Chrome or Mozilla?